# best value for curl timeout and connection timeout

Tags: php, curl

Greetings everyone

I am working on a small crawling engine and am using curl to request pages from various websites. Question is what do suggest should I set my connection_timeout and timeout values to? Stuff I would normally be crawling would be pages with lots of images and text.

Comment: if you want to crawl, you should set to no-timeout, instead spawn a curl at one-time (sequentially), you should fork multiple processes to curl

Comment: @ zerkms : wasn't aware. thanx

Comment: @ ajreal : thanx for the pointer. Will look into that in the future. So do suggest for single page at a time what would be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set it too high then your script will be slow as a one url that is down will take all the time you set in CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to finish processing. If you are not using proxies then you can just set the following values

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT = 3
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 1

Then you can go through failed urls at a later time to double check on them.

Answer (score 10):

cURL knows two different timeouts.
For `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` it doesn't matter how much text the site contains or how many other resources like images it references because this is a connection timeout and even the server cannot know about the size of the requested page until the connection is established.
For `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` it does matter. Even large pages require only a few packets on the wire, but the server may need more time to assemble the output. Also the number of redirects and other things (e.g. proxies) can significantly increase response time.

Generally speaking the "best value" for timeouts depends on your requirements and conditions of the networks and servers. Those conditions are subject of change. Therefore there is no "one best value".
I recommend to use rather short timeouts and retry failed downloads later.

Btw cURL does not automatically download resources referenced in the response. You have to do this manually with further calls to `curl_exec` (with fresh timeouts).

Answer (score 1):

The best response is the rik's one.

I have a Proxy Checker and in my benchmarks I saw that most of working Proxies takes less than 10 seconds to connect.

So I use 10 seconds for ConnectionTimeOut and TimeOut but that's in my case, you have to decide how many time you want to use so start with big values, use curl_getinfo to see time benchmarks and decrease the value.

Note: A proxy that takes more than 5 or 10 seconds to connect is useless for me, that's why I use that values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If your target is a proxy to query another site, such a cascading connection will require fairly long period like these values to execute the curl calls.

Especially when you encountered intermittent curl problems, please check these values first.

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
```

Comment: how many different websites have you tried this with? how many pages? whats the success rate like?

Comment: it actually worked pretty well... this was in one of my proxy scanning scripts so it was expecting long connection and response times